# Search from a *.txt and copy files to new directory

Tags: linux, bash, osx-mavericks

I have a *.txt file with lines of file names, over 500 of them. No paths are includes, just the file names. I want to point to a directory on a server that has subdirectories with files in it, search the *.txt file for the file names and copy anything it finds to a new directory (no need for subdirectories here).

Having a hard time finding anything that works. Tried xargs and rsync --files-from but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
find directory/on/server/ -type f |
while read f
do
    if fgrep -q "$(basename "$f")" '*.txt'; then
        cp "$f" new/directory/
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this, modified to include the paths to the .txt file and the source/destination folders, and it ran but did not return any files. Not sure why. This is exactly what I ran in a shell. I was CD'ed to /ARCHIVE just to be sure it knew where to look.

`find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/ -type f |
while read f
do
    if fgrep -q "$(basename "$f")" '/Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/02052018_file_list.txt'; then
        cp "$f" /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/02062018_OTMM_Missing/
    fi
done`

Comment: I should mention that these files are definitely on the server, they're just scattered throughout /ARCHIVE

Comment: What basename returns and records in .txt can be in a bit different format. Try printing it if fgrep fails: `find /from/path -type f | while read f; do bf="$(basename "$f")"; if fgrep -q "$bf" list.txt; then cp -v "$f" /to/path; else echo mismatch: $bf; fi; done` . (Also if that's _exactly_ what you run and you do it as a one-liner, then it lacks several semicolons)